# .NET formbuilder / auto form interface / generic data structures

Tags: .net, forms, sitecore

We have a request from a customer for an interface which allows them to specify arbitary fields for products for use in spec sheets. I can think of a couple of ways to do this:

- We could build some kind of data interface in .NET from scratch - could be expensive and time-consuming
- We could leverage Sitecore's (our CMS) form builder module and use Sitecore as the DB backend - could be hard to search/report on
- We could use some other 3rd party off-the-shelf tool for this

Is there a good product which provides:

- An interface to end users to arbitarily add/remove control fields for objects, and to auto-build forms including those interfaces?

Comment: Is the entire site running on Sitecore CMS? Which version? Is WFFM installed and being used already?

Comment: We are using Sitecore 6.1 . I don't know whether WFFM has been installed - probably not

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you need this for reports-like definitions I would suggest DevExpress XtraReports which includes a full royalty free end user designer that really rocks (also has Ribbon UI), see here:

[End-User Report Designer](http://devexpress.com/products/net/reporting/user-designer.xml)

if you really need to design Windows Forms, either some commercial tools, I don't know any right now, or you can also host/embed the Visual Studio Form Designer which I guess requires a Visual Studio license in all client machines willing to use it: [Create And Host Custom Designers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163634.aspx)  - See the paragraph *The Hosting Form*